# Giving a View a ≥ Height Constraint gives me 'Need Constraints for: Y position or height' (Swift)

Tags: swift, view, autolayout

I am trying to set up a view that contains 3 labels and a button, and I would like the view's height to be based on how tall the text is (it will take more lines on small phones vs on large phones), and I want the labels to have their height determined by how much text they have. The view would then be vertically centred. Leading and Trailing are fixed. This returns an error however and doesn't seem to work as intended. Am I doing this right or did I miss something?

Thank you in advance for any tips.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing give center horizontally and center vertically constraints to the `view` and also give leading and trailing constraints to the top two labels

see I have done the same

[image]

steps:
1. Took a view which is grey in color
2. Add 3 labels
3. Give height to each label
4. give top bottom leading and trailing constraint to each label
5. now either give leading & trailing constraint to the view or just give center horizontally
6. give center vertically to the uiview

[image]